# form.serialise is returning null to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a new programmer and I am trying to add a row in the database using ajax, by sending the new row with form.serialise. The model new row that i am sending is a  **part** of the main model that is used to create a view.

I know there is a tedious way of going through each column to match the column of the table in the database, however, I want to use the easier option-using ajax.

This is a part of my model used to create a view:

```
    public List <Appliance> Appliances { get; set; }


    public Appliance NewAppliance { get; set; }
    public string DepositTotalBalance { get; set; }

    public string DepositGiven { get; set; }
    public string DepositReturned { get; set; }
```

This is my controller method:

```
              public ActionResult CreateCheck(Appliance NewAppliance)
    {
            db.Appliances.InsertOnSubmit(app);
        db.SubmitChanges();

        var appIndb = (from a in db.Appliances
                             where a.ApartmentID == app.ApartmentID
                             select a).LastOrDefault();

              var applianceNew= appRepo.Add(appIndb );
                  return Json(new { success = true, appliance = 
             applianceNew}, 
                     JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                      }
```

This is my view - my fields in the form are ALL 
                          html.editorfor or hiddenfor- i have not specified 
                         names for any of 
                         them:

```
                     <form id="hidden-form-appliance">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-horizontal">


                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


                    <br />

                    <div class="flex-container">
                        <div class="flex-container flex-vericalDirection">
                            <p class="removeMargin">Appliance Name </p>
                            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewAppliance.ApplianceName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
                            <div class="inputModal" id="applianceNameDiv">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewAppliance.ApplianceName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "applianceName" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewAppliance.ApplianceName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="flex-container flex-vericalDirection">
                            <p class="removeMargin"> Unit</p>
                            <div class="inputModal">
                                @{ var unitsList = new List<SelectListItem>();


                                    foreach (var item in Model.AllApartmentsForID)
                                    {
                                        var unitType = new SelectListItem();
                                        unitType.Value = item.ApartmentID.ToString();
                                        unitType.Text = item.ApartmentNumber;


                                        unitsList.Add(unitType);
                                    }
                                }
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NewAppliance.ApartmentID, unitsList, "Select Unit", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ap_ApartmentID" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewAppliance.ApartmentID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


                            </div>
                        </div>






                    </div>



                    <div class="flex-container">

                        <div class="flex-container flex-vericalDirection">
                            <p class="removeMargin"> Make</p>
                            <div class="inputModal">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewAppliance.Make, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "editedDistrict" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewAppliance.Make, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex-container flex-vericalDirection">
                            <p class="removeMargin"> Model</p>
                            <div class="inputModal">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewAppliance.Model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "editedDistrict" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewAppliance.Model, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>



                    <div class="flex-container flex-vericalDirection removeMargin">
                        <p class="removeMargin">Description</p>

                        <textarea class="text-area-input-form">
                        @Model.NewAppliance.DescriptionDetails

                    </textarea>
                    </div>


                    <div class="flex-container">


                        <div class="flex-container flex-vericalDirection">
                            <p class="removeMargin"> Store</p>
                            <div class="inputModal">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewAppliance.Store, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "editedAddress" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewAppliance.Store, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex-container flex-vericalDirection">
                            <p class="removeMargin"> Cost</p>
                            <div class="inputModal">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewAppliance.Cost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "editedAddress" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewAppliance.Cost, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="flex-container flex-vericalDirection">
                        <p class="removeMargin"> Installed On</p>
                        <div class="inputModal">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewAppliance.DateOfInstallment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "datepicker" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewAppliance.DateOfInstallment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
                </form>
```

This is the js:

```
                                  $('.btn.btn-- 
                         primary.saveNewAppliance').on('click', 
                               function () {

            alert($('#hidden-form-appliance').serialize());

            $.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("CreateCheck", "Appliance")',
                data:{ NewAppliance: $('#hidden-form- 
                 appliance').serialize()},
              success: function(data) {
        if (data) {  // check if data is defined
           if (data.success) { // if success is true
               alert("It Worked!"); 

               }
             }
          }
         });
```

**Update:**    This is the source code:

```
            <form id="hidden-form-appliance">
                <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" 
             value="MLW1wQJnd0WnHyzEaOJO6kAEVm-r_9YYhDliWfy28Qxs6- 
                 Q6kabsK48RICT5uAIhtJ1WQ3Hrq6S-axQwIoMw5F32t6webLXW- 
                     T7npEad1lkn-7dVDO6HFyGcXsJpv2ayhiithucgvg3Ro2kd8Pk5MQ2" 
                         />

                               <input class="form-control text-box single- 
                            line" id="applianceName" 
                        name="NewAppliance.ApplianceName" 
                          type="text" value="" />



                                <select class="form-control" data- 
                           val="true" data-val-number="The field 
                            ApartmentID must be a number." 
                             id="ap_ApartmentID" 
                           name="NewAppliance.ApartmentID"><option 
                       value="">Select Unit</option>
                            </select>


                                <input class="form-control text-box single- 
                          line" id="editedDistrict" 
                               name="NewAppliance.Make" type="text" 
                value="" />

                                <input class="form-control text-box single- 
                            line" id="editedDistrict" 
                               name="NewAppliance.Model" type="text" 
                                           value="" />






                    <div class="flex-container flex-vericalDirection 
                            removeMargin">
                        <p class="removeMargin">Description</p>

                        <textarea class="text-area-input-form">


                    </textarea>



                                <input class="form-control text-box single- 
                               line" id="editedAddress" 
                           name="NewAppliance.Store" type="text" value="" 
                                  />



                                <input class="form-control text-box single- 
                                       line" data-val="true" data-val- 
                                   number="The field Cost must be a 
                                   number." id="editedAddress" 
                               name="NewAppliance.Cost" type="text" 
                           value="" />






                            <input class="form-control text-box single- 
                     line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field 
                     DateOfInstallment must be a date." data-val- 
                         required="The DateOfInstallment field is 
                         required." id="datepicker" 
                     name="NewAppliance.DateOfInstallment" type="date" 
                       value="" />



            </form>
```

I get the error "Value cannot be null". (Appliance model is being sent as null).

**Update 2:**

console.log($('#hidden-form-appliance').serialize()) yields:

```
Appliance.ApplianceName=jhbk&Appliance.ApartmentID=1388&Appliance.ApplianceID=0&Appliance.Make=hhj&Appliance.Model=hku&Appliance.DescriptionDetails=bhjk&Appliance.Store=gjh&Appliance.Cost=789&Appliance.DateOfInstallment=09%2F08%2F2009
```

Anyone can help? Thank you

Comment: Can you edit your question and give us more information about how the generated HTML is looking like of your form? Are the fields there having a specified name attribute value?

Comment: please see above edits - i have attached now the complete form

Comment: Thanks, Jane, but that is not the generated HTML. It is the markup. Your generated HTML is what is displayed in the browser. You can view that with View Source. Please copy the generated HTML into your question as well.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad please see updates thank you

Comment: The form has an id of buildingForm, while your code searches for a form with the id of hidden-form-appliance. This seems to be the problem. What is console.log($('#buildingForm').serialize()); yield?

Comment: Please see above updates

Comment: Sorry i had posted the wrong source code.please see above updates. Thank you!

Comment: Then the id you are using seems to be correct.

Comment: And whats the issue?

Comment: I don't know. If somehow it could be reproduced, inside a Fiddle, for example, then I could look into it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chayareitzer/fd4eph9s/2/

Comment: JSFiddle is not able to convert your ASP.NET code. You could put your generated HTML and Javascript into a JSFiddle.

Comment: I can see now that the controller is getting the form as a string and not converting it to the appliance object automatically. Any ideas why?

Comment: Jane, is this true only for the Fiddle, or is it true for the actual application as well? In the case of the Fiddle the answer is simple: the Fiddle doesn't use your server's backend technology.

Answer (score 0):

> i have not specified names for any of them

It appears that you specify the editors' id attributes, for example:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewAppliance.Cost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "editedAddress" } })
```

what may affect the resultant request data pairs. Since you use the strong-typed editors, try not to specify this html attribute explicitly. If you need to manipulate them in js/css, try to operate the css class(es) instead.

Comment: I thought this is the way to add css classes, could you give me an example of how to add css class

Comment: The ID attribute of a form field is not used when serialising or submitting form data, the name is used instead